# How to filter contacts by name

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm developing a windows phone 7 application.
I'm trying to understand how I'm supposed to filter contacts by letters. I want to display the keyboard to the user and show all the contacts. If the user pushes "a" everyone with an a in the name should be shown.

Please tell me this is possible. I'm getting more and more frustrated with this API..

Comment: As I understand you need something similar to jump list? http://bewisephonecontrols.codeplex.com/

Comment: The jump list doesn't filter as you type. `AutoCompleteBox` would be a better choice.

Comment: Correct, but it could be what the app needs.

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier if you actually show us some code to show where you've got to so far.

It sounds like what you need is the `AutoCompleteBox` from the [Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone 7](http://silverlight.codeplex.com). There's a good post on WindowsPhoneGeek.com: [AutoCompleteBox for WP7 in depth](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/autocompletebox-for-wp7-in-depth), which should show you how to use this control.